# How to insert a variable in windows.location href?

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to search but I didn't find any solution to insert a sql variable inside of windows.location.href = "";

I have already tried this:

```html
window.location.href = "<?php echo $up1 ?>"
```

I have found some examples in php but not in javascript

But it's not working and I have searched, and still I can not find anything on the web.

I have tried the example but I think the way i did it, is not correct.

All my code:

```html
<?php
    $up1 = $userRow['up1'];
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
     header("Location: index.php");
    }
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_points);
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_voucher);
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_level);
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_wallet);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT up1 FROM settings");
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $up1 = $up1;

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
      var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
      if (key == 13) { 
        // enter key do nothing
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }      
    }
    </script>

    <script>
            window.oncontextmenu = function () {
                console.log("Right Click Disabled");
                return false;
            }


        </script>



    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function disableselect(e){  
    return false  
    }  

    function reEnable(){  
    return true  
    }  

    //if IE4+  
    document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")  
    document.oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false")  
    //if NS6  
    if (window.sidebar){  
    document.onmousedown=disableselect  
    document.onclick=reEnable  
    }
    </script>


    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div  id='exemple' data-up='<?php echo $up1;?>'>
    <script>
    function goToBing() {
     //window.location.href = "<?php echo $up1; ?>"
    var test=$("#exemple").attr('data-up);
       window.location.href=test;
    }
    </script>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><a href="http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt" onclick="goToBing();return false;">Click To Confirm Please</a></center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why should `$up1 = $up1;` work? Did you check the content of your rendered javascript code?

Comment: Also it seems that you are missing jQuery (or other library using $) and implenting a `div` in head which will fall down at some browsers. Oh and $row is not set...

Comment: Have you tried <div><?php echo $up1;?></div> to check if your php code is writing out the url you want to redirect to? If that works, then start looking at the javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
 <div  id='exemple' data-up='<?php echo $up1;?>'>
 </div>
```

in jquery :

```
var test=$("#exemple").attr('data-up);
   window.location.href=test;
```